# While loop is starting even when parameters aren't met

Tags: python, while-loop

I've been trying to run this Python code:

```
type = input("Please enter the file type ('video' or 'audio'): ")

while type != "video" or type != "audio":
    type = input("Please enter a valid format ('video' or 'audio'): ")
    if type == "video" or type == "audio":
        break
```

The problem: Even when the conditions aren't met (e.g: the format is 'video') the while loop begins, you can break out of it by simply typing the required format again, but it's very inconvenient, any help?

Comment: type would be "audio" or "video" so your statement will always be true cause if `type!="video"` is `False` (means that type is "video") then `type!="audio"` will be `True` ... so your condition will be always `True`

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Related: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](/q/23294658/4518341)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct code is:

```
t = ""

while t not in ["video", "audio"]:
    t = input("Please enter a valid format ('video' or 'audio'): ")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while type != "video" or type != "audio"
```

That while condition will ALWAYS be true.

If they entered "video", then the `!= "audio"` part will be true.

If they entered "audio", then the `!= "video"` part will be true.

If they entered anything else, then both parts will be true.

Use `and` instead of `or`:

```
while type != "video" and type != "audio"
```

Or, even better, check for membership in a list:

```
while type not in ["video", "audio"]:
```

And better still, don't use built-in names such as `type` for your variables.

Answer (score 1):

Change `or` by `and`:

```
# HERE -------------v
while t != "video" and t != "audio":
    print(t)
    t = input("Please enter a valid format ('video' or 'audio'): ")
```

Answer (score 0):

`NOT x OR NOT y` is not the opposite of `x OR y`, that's `NOT (x OR y)`. Or, using De Morgan's laws, `NOT x AND NOT y`.

That said, using `not in` is much simpler. See [Adrian B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69845488/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

I would put this logic in its own function to avoid complicated loop structures and make the code more readable. I would do something like this:

```
def get_media_type_input():
    while True:
        media_type = input("Please enter a valid format ('video' or 'audio'): ")
        if media_type in ("video", "audio"):
            return media_type
        else:
            print(f"Invalid media type {media_type}. Try again")

...

media_type = get_media_type_input()
```

You could then extend this to make the method more generic:

```
def get_format_type_input(title, choices):
    while True:
        choice = input(
            f"Please enter a valid {title} format "
            f"({', '.join(choices)}): "
        )
        if choice in choices:
            return choice
        else:
            print(f"Invalid {title} format '{choice}'. Try again.")


media_type = get_format_type_input("media", ["video", "audio"])
```